# Using window handles (win32gui) instead of captions in python

Tags: python, handle, caption, enumerate

```
import win32ui
import win32gui

def WindowExists(windowname):
    try:
        win32ui.FindWindow(None, windowname)
        
    except win32ui.error:
        return False
    else:
        return True

hwndName = "Main Window Program"
         
if WindowExists(hwndName):
    print ("Program is running")
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, hwndName)   
else:
    print ("Program is not running")  

child_handles = []

def all_ok(hwnd, param):
    child_handles.append(hwnd)    
            
win32gui.EnumChildWindows(hwnd, all_ok, None)

print (child_handles)
```

The code above is working perfectly fine for me to be able to detect if "Main Window Program" is running, I am also able to enumerate all the child windows off of that. My problem however is I dont know how to use handles instead of captions, so instead of `hwnd = "Main Window Program"` I could use `hwnd = 0xC0D57` (or whatever the handle is).

Also whats the best input method do a control? postmessage, sendmessage etc?

Comment: Ok updated this post to clean out some of the useless information, hopefully someone can help!

Comment: Never used it in a Python environment, and I do not know exactly how to process the callback, but in C or C++ the right API function to call is `BOOL EnumWindows(WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, LPARAM lParam);`